# Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with array literal Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I am trying to my code Swift 2 to Swift 3 but I can not convert following code.

When I use Any instead of AnyObject I am getting error like: Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with array literal in "items:" part.

When I user AnyObject and then use the "name:" part as AnyObject getting error like: Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with array literal

I could not find the best solution for it.
How can I do it?

```
var menus: [[String: AnyObject]] {
        return [
            ["name": NSLocalizedString("General", comment: ""),
                "items": [
                    MenuItem(icon: UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(FontAwesome.Heart, textColor: TubeTrends.Settings.foregroundColor, size: TubeTrends.Settings.menuIconSize), title: NSLocalizedString("Favorites", comment: ""), action: { (indexPath) -> Void in
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.favoritesVideoListVC(), animated: true)
                    }),                    
                ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 heterogenous literal collection types must be annotated explicitly, for example

```
var menus: [[String: Any]] {
    let dict : [String:Any] = ["name": NSLocalizedString("General", comment: ""),
            "items": [
                MenuItem(icon: UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(FontAwesome.Heart, textColor: TubeTrends.Settings.foregroundColor, size: TubeTrends.Settings.menuIconSize), title: NSLocalizedString("Favorites", comment: ""), action: { (indexPath) -> Void in
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.favoritesVideoListVC(), animated: true)
                }),                    
              ]
            ]
        return [dict]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help vadian. With this solution I am getting  Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with array literal error in "items:" part

Comment: Then you need to declare (and annotate) the value for `items` separately, too.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Swift can't simply infer "Any" for heterogeneous collections.